# Counting number of occurrences of string matched to another column

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, count

```
df = {'msg':['i am so happy thank you',
'sticker omitted',
'sticker omitted',
'thank you for your time!'
,'sticker omitted','hello there'],
'number_of_stickers':['2','0','0','1','0','0']} ##This column 'number_of_stickers' is what i am aiming to achieve. Currently, i don't have this column.

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

Above is what I am trying to achieve. I currently **Do not** have the column 'number_of_stickers'. This column would be my end goal.

I am trying to count the number of rows with "sticker omitted" and append the row **above** the chain of "sticker omitted" with the number of occurrences. I would like to append onto the new column 'number_of_stickers'

To give you some context, I am analysing whatsapp text data, and I thought it would be useful to see how many stickers were sent right after a chat was sent. This also shows the tonality and sentiments of the conversation.

#### Update:

I have posted a solution (credits to @JacoSolari) which would work for the problem I'm solving. Added 1-2 lines (if statement) on top of his codes so that we do not face a problem at the end of the dataframe (range issues).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I just started learning python and I've honestly been stuck for quite a while. It's terrible when I don't really know where to even begin... Been learning only for 1.5 months, so forgive me.

Comment: That's okay, but you won't ever learn if you get all your answers from the internet. Try to modify the answers you have received so that they work for your exact case instead of asking the people who answered to edit their code to satisfy every use-case. Here's a good resource on [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job. I could not find a solution that only uses pandas functions (it might be possible to do it). Anyways, I left some comments in the code to describe my approach.

```
# create data
df_dict = {'msg':['i am so happy thank you',
'sticker omitted',
'sticker omitted',
'thank you for your time!'
,'sticker omitted']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=df_dict)

# build column for sticker counts after message 
sticker_counts = []
for index, row in df.iterrows(): # iterating over df rows
    flag = True
    count = 0
    # when a sticker row is encountered, just put 0 in the count column
    # when a non-sticker row is encountered do the following
    if row['msg'] != 'sticker omitted': 
        k = 1 # to check rows after the non-sticker row
        while flag:
            # if the index + k row is a sticker increase the count for index and k
            if df.loc[index + k].msg == 'sticker omitted': 
                count += 1
                k += 1
                # when reached the end of the database, break the loop
                if index + k +1 > len(df):
                    flag = False
            else:
                flag = False
                k = 1
    sticker_counts.append(count)
df['sticker_counts'] = sticker_counts
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I still face a slight issue with this, but I'll figure it out myself :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a common technique to check for the other values and take cumsum to identify the blocks:

```
omitted = df.msg.ne('sticker omitted').cumsum()

df['number_of_stickers'] = np.where(omitted.duplicated(), 0,
                                    omitted.groupby(omitted).transform('size')-1)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for helping! I don't think this worked for the question I am trying to solve, unfortunately. I wasn't quite clear with my problem. I have since refreshed my problem, and would appreciate if you could help with it! :) Thank you!

Comment: @Laz My code returns a new column `number_of_stickers` which matches your column in the sample data. And I don't see your question updated. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Hi Quang, I have uploaded a pic on imgur to show you what I mean, using a small section of my actual dataframe. 
https://imgur.com/a/4GBsCdw
Somehow, your codes worked well for my test df in my question. However, I'm not sure why there aren't any results when I tested with a small section of my dataframe...

Comment: To be completely honest I think this should be the accepted answer. It only uses pandas and is more elegant than my solution. This is exactly the solution I failed to find using only pandas (thanks @QuangHoang I have learned something from your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You've actually got it all right so far, and your data is substantial for a easy yet functional algorithm!

Here is a little piece of code I coded up for this problem:

```py
#ss
df = {'msg':['i am so happy thank you',
'sticker omitted',
'sticker omitted',
'thank you for your time!'
,'sticker omitted'],
'number_of_stickers':['2','0','0','1','0']}
j = 0
newarr = [] # new array for use
for i in df["number_of_stickers"]:
    if(not int(i)==0):
       newarr.append([df["msg"][j], int(i)]) # will store each data in a array
       #access the number of it by using element 1(newarr[1]) and the msg by newarr[0]
    j+=1;
#se
#feel free to do whatever you want after ss to se

pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

se being snippet end and ss snippet start.

Hope this helps! Just comment below if it doesn't!

also you have to refeed the new array to the dict.

Comment: The question is tagged as python

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping with the question. I don't think this code worked... What I got from it was an array of 'msg' with the index at the back of it. 

ie. "i am so happy thank you1"; "sticker omitted2"

I have refreshed my question to be clearer on what I'm looking for. Would be really helpful if you could help!! :) Many thanks

Comment: Hey not a problem at all! I've figured it out, and I'll post the updated solution onto this platform for everyone. Feel free to contribute more solutions too! :) Very thankful for your contribution

Comment: nice ok will do in spare time

Answer (score 0):

I have edited @JacoSolari's codes (with the help of a kind soul) to match the needs of the problem I'm trying to solve. Please find the code below useful.

```
sticker_counts = []
msg_index = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows(): # iterating over df rows
    flag = True
    count = 0
    # when a sticker row is encountered, just put 0 in the count column
    # when a non-sticker row is encountered do the following
    if row['msg'] != 'sticker omitted': 
        k = 1 # to check rows after the non-sticker row
        while flag:
            print(f'i{msg_index} flag{flag} len{len(df)}')
            # if the index + k row is a sticker increase the count for index and k
            msg_index=index + k 
            if msg_index >= len(df):
                break
            if df.loc[msg_index].msg == 'sticker omitted': 
                count += 1
                k += 1
                # when reached the end of the database, break the loop
                if msg_index +1 > len(df):
                    flag = False
                    print(f'i{msg_index} flag{flag}')
            else:
                flag = False
                k = 1                
    sticker_counts.append(count)
df['sticker_counts'] = sticker_counts
print(df)
```